# Arduino RFID-RC522 can't read all rfid cards

Tags: arduino, mfrc522

I just got my RFID-RC522 reader & writer. It came with a blank white RFID card and a tag. Both of them prints out the data. But when i try my other cards at home that are also RFID cards then they don't work. 
It prints out the Card UID but and the first sector and starts spaming:

> pcd authentication() failed timeout in communication

I used miguelbalboa/rfid library from GitHub and i used the Dumpinfo example. The RC522 works but not for other cards. Is there a limitation on the RC522?

Answer (score 1):

RFID tags have a working frequency (RFID-RC522 is 13,56MHz) and protocol RFID-RC522 can read Mifare tags.

Most likely problems: 
 - The RFID scanned uses another frequency (125kHz for example).
 - The RFID scanned uses a different protocol.

There are different RFID tags, frequencies and protocols. There is no one size fits all.